# delegate command with function with parameter

Tags: c#

```
ModelRequestCommand = new DelegateCommand(PopulateModelRequest);
```

has no error and is fine, but I want to pass a parameter (int ProgramID) into populate model request. ProgramID is define by

```
this.ProgramId = ProgramID;
```

It gives an error when I try

```
ModelRequestCommand = new DelegateCommand(PopulateModelRequest(int ProgramID);
```

how do i go about this?

a button is binding to ModelRequestCommand in WPF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you tried to declare a parameter during a function invocation. You then tried to pass the result of that invocation (which should have been `void`) to a constructor expecting an `Action<object>` or possibly an `Action` delegate. You just can't do that.

Again, The `ICommand` interfaces `Execute` method (which is really what you are implementing) looks like this:

```
void Execute(object parameter)
```

Where parameter is passed via the `CommandParameter` property on the calling object (ie, a `Button`). The `DelegateCommand` object implements this and calls the delegate passed on the constructor with the same arguments (some versions of that class will allow you to pass a simple `Action` and `DelegateCommand` ignores `parameter` for you).

To fix it, either pass `ProgramID` on `CommandParameter` and do this:

```
private void PopulateModelRequest(object parameter)
{
   int programId = (int)parameter;
}
```

or something like

```
new DelegateCommand(() => PopulateModelRequest(ProgramId));

private void PopulateModelRequest(int programId)
{
}
```

The second is creating a closure over ProgramId, so if you would have access to that field *anyways* in your method, just use it instead of passing it in.

Answer (score 1):

That error is because when you add parantesis to a method like this

```
PopulateModelRequest(int ProgramID)
```

you just tell the compiler that you want to invoke the `PopulateModelRequest` method. It is not possible even to invoke the method, because you also specify the type of the parameter, where it expects only the parameter, so what you are trying to do si basicaly wrong.

If you want to assign a delegate to `ModelRequestCommand` then you should do as in the first line of code:

```
ModelRequestCommand = new DelegateCommand(PopulateModelRequest);
```

I may have misunderstood your question, but definetly it will be better for you to take a look at an [article ablout delegates and events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) before you go on.

Comment: I don't think you can call a command object like a function... That said, I heartily agree that the OP needs to get a better understanding of delegates before continuing.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET even though, the parantesis mark an invocation of a method in C# and in many other programming language, so even if it's not possible, I stated that by adding paranthesis he is trying to tell the compiler that he wants to invoke a method

Comment: I agree with all that, I'm referring to your last line of code (`ModelRequestCommand(ProgramId)`) `DelegateCommand` is a very specific object in WPF that is a generic implementation of `ICommand`

Comment: @BradleyDotNET perfect, thank you for telling me, I did not realized that is not a simple delegate, it is a DelegateCommand. I will just remove it, as I do not how to work with it properly

Comment: I just started C# two days ago, diving head first and learning as I go but also have to complete my tasks as I learn, thanks to this site I can accomplish both goals

Comment: @bossman1111 thanks! I am glad that you appreciate it, it will cover all you need to know about delegates and hope it will be easy enough to understand as you have just started C#